# AC Voltage to Spark Plug

Tags: ac, spark

To get a spark plug to fire I read that it requires approximately 12,000 Volts. If I have an ac generator giving a RMS Voltage of about 10 Volts (pretty small) what do I need to do to get the spark plug to fire? I was thinking about possibly adding a step up transformer but unsure whether or not that would even be possible. So what is typically done with an ac circuit to get enough voltage to allow the spark plug to fire? I would like the spark plug be able to fire periodically like an engine.

Comment: What is  the wattage capacity of your AC generator at 10 volts?

Comment: Will, give a bit more detail in your question (and not in the comments) about what you are trying to achieve. Is the end goal just improved understanding and the wild joy of creating a spark or are you trying to make something else that requires a spark. It may help if you research car ignition systems and magnetos.

Comment: What would you do if you knew the wattage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way that a spark plug is fired is to provide a low-voltage DC pulse to an ignition coil. An ignition coil is a pulse transformer that is specifically designed for that purpose. If you search "ignition coil spark circuit" or anything like that, you should be able to find lots of detailed information with diagrams. Very little power is required. Any simple AC to DC power supply will profide a good starting point if you must use AC. Here is the basic diagram:

[image]

Comment: So if you have commutator and a voltage dc of 1 volt. All you need is an ignition coil?

Comment: Ignition coils that are easily available will work with 6 volts. One volt would probably produce a spark across a very small gap.

Comment: So if I get it cranking up to 6 volts what should I be looking for in an ignition coil?

Comment: In ignition coil for a motorcycle, tractor or car can be found in a junkyard.

Comment: You may find an ignition coil from a magneto motor (old lawnmower etc) will also work, in parallel with its capacitor. Close the magnetic circuit with an iron bar across the pole pieces, spaced from them with a couple of sheets of paper. They would have been about 0.5mm from a permanent magnet in the flywheel. Connect a few volts across the primary.  Wait a few milliseconds until the current builds up (one coil I have here measures 0.7 ohms, so about 4A from 3V). Disconnect the voltage and the inductive kick should give a nice high voltage pulse from the secondary.